# Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax not registering ajax type

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

When I am using Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax , I get Error.
Error message says:
Error Processing callback function.Auto refresh terminated. Error: "MyAjaxClass" is undefined.
My code looks like:

```
public class MyAjaxClass
{
   Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite
    public string SaveData (int count)
    {
        return something;
    }

}
public partial class webaccess: Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(MyAjaxClass));
    }
}

I added below config handlers in web.config.
 <system.webServer>    
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <modules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
        <add verb="POST,GET" name="Ajax" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax" />
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx"  type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd"   type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="ScriptResource"  verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
```

Please let me know what else I can do.

Comment: Where you have defined your `MyAjaxClass` class??

Comment: public class MyAjaxClass
{
   Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite]
    public string SaveData (int count)
    {
        return something;
    }

}

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error in your code

```
 Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite
```

replace it with

```
  [Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your `MyAjaxClass` inside the `public partial class webaccess: Page` your code should look like this

```
public partial class webaccess : Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(MyAjaxClass));
}
public class MyAjaxClass
{
    { Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite] public string SaveData (int count) { return something; } }
}
}
```